# General Linq Data Method

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic, reflection

I would like to create general method that gets data from Linq based on given parameters such as: table , field1 and field2.

one method that will be used instead of these 2 specific ones for example:

```
public void DistributeCB(ComboBox cb)
    {
        BooksDBDataContext db = new BooksDBDataContext();
        Type T = db.GetType();

        //Authors table
        var data =db.Authors.Select(author => new
        {
            Id = author.AuthorId, //field 1
            Value = author.AuthorName //field 2
        });
        cb.ValueMember = "Id";
        cb.DisplayMember = "Value";
        cb.DataSource = data;
    }

    public void DistributeCB2(ComboBox cb)
    {
        BooksDBDataContext db = new BooksDBDataContext();

        //Publishers table
        var data = db.Publishers.Select(publisher => new
        {
            Id = publisher.PublishingId, //field 1
            Value = publisher.PublishingName //field 2
        });
        cb.ValueMember = "Id";
        cb.DisplayMember = "Value";
        cb.DataSource = data;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you don't mind passing the entity as a generic type instead of a string parameter you could try:

For Linq-to-Entities:

```
public void Distribute<TEntity>(ComboBox cb, 
                                DbContext db, 
                                string valueField, 
                                string displayField) 
                        where TEntity : class
{

    //Publishers table
    var data = db.Set<TEntity>() as IEnumerable;

    cb.ValueMember = valueField;
    cb.DisplayMember = displayField;
    cb.DataSource = data;
}
```

For Linq-to-SQL:

```
public void Distribute<TEntity>(ComboBox cb, 
                                DataContext db, 
                                string valueField, 
                                string displayField) 
                        where TEntity : class
{

    //Publishers table
    var data = db.GetTable<TEntity>() as IEnumerable;

    cb.ValueMember = valueField;
    cb.DisplayMember = displayField;
    cb.DataSource = data;
}
```

Comment: The problem here is that you'll be fetching all of the columns from the database, rather than just the two you need.

Comment: its good for my purpose because i want to use it only with tables containing only 2 fields, but i got error from the editor- and i'm not sure what it means :(

Comment: Error 1 'BooksApp.BooksDBDataContext' does not contain a definition for 'Set' and no extension method 'Set' accepting a first argument of type 'BooksApp.BooksDBDataContext' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I assumed you were using Linq-to-Entities.  Added an example for Linq-to-SQL.

Comment: Thanks a lot man, appreciated and btw it works for me without the "as IEnumerable" :)

Answer (score 0):

i tried few things and it works but i'm sure about it's code:

```
    public void Distribute<TEntity>(ComboBox cb, BooksDBDataContext db, string valueField, string displayField)
                    where TEntity : class
    {


        var data = db.GetTable<TEntity>();


        cb.ValueMember = valueField;
        cb.DisplayMember = displayField;
        cb.DataSource = data;
    }
```